# Ruby - Unexpected Hash data structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

A simple question:

In rails I get as response an hash like this:

```
{"success":true,"new_id":816704027}
```

So, the difference from a normal structure I guess is- "new_id": -instead of- new_id:

Does anyone know how to retrieve the data labelled "new_id"?
The usual array["new_id"] doesn't work.

The response to the code:

```
new_customer_id = @response.body
puts new_customer_id
puts new_customer_id["new_id"]
```

is simply:

```
=> {"success":true,"new_id":816704028}
=> new_id
```

I come from the implementation of JSON_response. Anyway, they changed the app and I don't have anymore a JSON message, but they use the method:

```
return_200(additional_items: {:new_id => "@customer.id"} )
```

More:

If I write:

```
new_customer_id = @response.body
puts new_customer_id
puts new_customer_id[:new_id]
```

the answer printed is simply:

```
=> {"success":true,"new_id":816704028}
```

and the request for the :new_id content does not to be received.

Much more interesting is the following:
After the fact that:

```
puts new_customer_id["new_id"]
```

prints:

```
=> new_id
```

If I write:

```
puts new_customer_id["new_id"][0]
puts new_customer_id["new_id"][1]
puts new_customer_id["new_id"][2]
...
```

I obtain:

```
=> n
=> e
=> w
...
```

Also:

if I write:

```
puts new_customer_id["new_"]
puts new_customer_id["new_i"]
```

I obtain:

```
=> new_
=> new_i
```

and if I write:

```
puts new_customer_id["new_id_anyOtherCharacter"]
```

I get nothing

Luca

Comment: Why doesn't `array["new_id"]` work? what errors do you get when using it?

Comment: Try this in Rails Console
`a = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode('{"success":true,"new_id":816704027}')`
then access it using `a["new_id"]`

Comment: @TamerShlash, the answer to your question is below

Comment: @LucaDanieli Please edit your question to add details, rather than adding them as an answer.

Comment: What is the result of `new_customer_id.class`?

Comment: @MaxWilliams. It writes String. So it's probably not a hash?

Comment: @MaxWilliams. Yes. It is a string, not an Hash. Using json_response solved the problem of this post. And so my problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a ruby object you are getting back. It's JSON.  You can get the new_id in a variety of ways:

`JSON.parse(@response.body)["new_id"]`

`JSON.parse(@response.body).symbolize_keys[:new_id]`

`JSON.parse(@response.body).with_indifferent_access[:new_id]`

Answer (score 0):

use params to get the value like:

```
new_id= array[:new_id]
```

Comment: He clearly said a "response" hash, not a params hash.

Comment: I have just changed the answer, please undo your down voting

Answer (score 0):

I bet the hash has a symbol key instead of a string key.  Try with `array[:new_id]`.

Comment: that doesn't work. I don't know why but it doesn't give me any answer. I updated the question, so you can read what happens